# Get the height of the Windows taskbar (Winapi)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, taskbar

How can I calculate the taskbar height, 
so that my winapi app starts up of it?
Now, as it is, when I launch my program,
 it starts and the bottom of it is placed behind the taskbar.
How can I tell my program to move
 above the taskbar as soon as it starts?
I'll mark the right answer.Thnx.

Comment: Use GetMonitorInfo() like Windows does, MONITORINFOEX.rcWork contains what you need.

Comment: Beware that some people hide the taskbar by default and only show on mouse over and others have them on the left/right side of the screen. And some do both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `SPI_GETWORKAREA` with [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the available screen size, excluding the taskbar, [`GetSystemMetrics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can get you the full screen size, so the taskbar size is just the difference of the axis that the taskbar is one, you should check which axis that is by comparing both axies, as the taskbar my not always be on the bottom.

Comment: Ok, that's the right answer(at least for now), thank you. Not trivial, as usual. Winapi's rules? :|

Comment: @A_nto2 `SystemParametersInfo` should have been several functions instead: one per parameter. I wonder if this is yet another 16-bit relic that has not been replaced.